# How to use Avenir in Latex

Tags: latex, xetex

How can I use font which is called with Avenir in latex? When I use the following

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Avenir}
```

I am getting following error:

```
The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX
```

Comment: Compile with `xelatex filename` or `lualatex filename` instead of `pdflatex filename`